# Select multiple elements from a list

Tags: r, list, subset

I have a list in R some 10,000 elements long. Say I want to select only elements, 5, 7, and 9. I'm not sure how I would do that without a for loop.

I want to do something like `mylist[[c(5,7,9]]` but that doesn't work. I've also tried the `lapply` function but haven't been able to get that working either.

Comment: From the documentation found at `?"[["`: *The most important distinction between `[`, `[[` and `$` is that the `[` can select more than one element whereas the other two select a single element.*

Comment: Further to @mrdwab's comment, this being the vectorised world of R, "a single element" may be a vector!

Answer (score 183, accepted):

`mylist[c(5,7,9)]` should do it.

You want the sublists returned as sublists of the result list; you don't use `[[]]` (or rather, the function is `[[`) for that -- as Dason mentions in comments, `[[` grabs the element.

Comment: Just to add some more detail - "[" will return a sublist so it makes sense that you could use multiple inputs with it.  "[[" will actually grab the element itself so it can only take a single input since it isn't returning a list (unless the element itself is a list).

Comment: Is this vectorized? I have two lists: `b` contains 10 million elements. `filter_bins` is a list where each element is an index. so to only get elements from `b` with the same index, I have 

`lapply(filter_bins, function(x) b[x, ])` 

so b[x, ] only returns a subset of the rows (where each element is chosen by filter_bins).. I hope this makes sense. My question is that this is very slow

Comment: @masfenix you should generate a new question describing the details.

Comment: Can the above solution be done with something like dplyr::select() and contains('some text")?

Comment: @Dason how do you then select multiple elements with [[?

Comment: @HermanToothrot You don't.  At least not directly.  You could lapply or sapply over the indices you want to extract and iteratively grab the corresponding element with `[[`. But if you want to extract multiple elements then really you're grabbing a sublist and you should just use `[`

Answer (score 2):

Glen_b's answer is the correct one. Below are some examples of how you can use it with pipes, functions like `lapply` and `map()`, and within a dataframe with list columns:

With pipes:

```
library(tidyverse)

x <- as.list(letters)
nums <- c(5, 7, 9)

x[nums] # Glen's answer

nums |> x[i = _] # using the native pipe

nums %>% {x[.]} # using magrittr's pipe
# nums %>% x[i = .] is equivalent
```

Using `map()`, `lapply()` etc.

```
y = list(as.list(letters), as.list(LETTERS))

map(y, \(x) x[nums]) # lambda function \(x) x[nums] is equivalent to ~ .x[nums] or function(x){x[nums]}
lapply(y, \(x) x[nums])
```

With list-type columns in dataframes:

```
df <- tibble(
    x = list(x)) # we need to put x within another list, as tibble() will unnest x otherwise

df |> 
  mutate(z = map(x, \(x) x[nums])) |> 
  pull(z)
```