extract values associated with multiple keys in R hash
Suppose I have a hash in R, e.g.
testing = hash()
testing[["a"]] = 1
testing[["b"]] = 2
testing[["c"]] = 3

For this toy example, I would like to extract the values associated with keys a,c so that the vector c(1,3) is returned.
I tried
testing[[c("a","c")]]

which isn't recognized, but surely there's some way to do this without creating a loop over the keys of interest?

This applies to lists in R more generally. Single brackets, not double brackets, are used for the sublist. So you want testing[c("a","c")]. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12119019/select-multiple-elements-from-a-list

testing[c("a","c")] returns a new hash. Is there a simple way to just return an output vector with (in my example) c(1,3)?

You can unlist the result (assuming you only store single, atomic values for each key) unlist(testing[c("a","c")]). That is also assuming your hash() is actually a list(). There is no base R hash() function. Are you using some other library?

Yes, I am using the hash library in R.

So I'm not just using a standard R list, but rather a hash specific to that library (i.e. unlist doesn't give the desired result, even though I assumed this was correct)

I looked at the documentation of the hash package and you can get the desired result with values(testing[c('a','c')]). It's good to always say what packages you are using when asking R questions.
